# wordpress: search in business directory plugin does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I am having problem with searching business directory for my wordpress. I am currently using https://businessdirectoryplugin.com/ for the business directory.

And there is this search link:
http://harta.net/developer-property-listing/

For example, if I type-in the word "Adenland", nothing comes up (and somehow it goes to advance search). It should be able to search the word i type in.

How can I solve this ?

below is a screenshot on how I enable the search. But somehow search is not working, is there something I should do ?

[image]

Comment: Why are you asking here? Ask for support from the developers of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use any other plugin as most of the plugins available. The most recent one I used is https://fulltextsearch.org/. I hope it solves your problem.